# HSV thresholding values for a tennis ball OpenCv

Tags: c++, opencv, hsv

I have tried to use the following values to threshold an image to find a tennis ball but I find nothing.

Here are the values I am using in my `inRange` call

```
cvScalar(0.11*256, 0.60*256, 0.20*256, 0)

cvScalar(0.14*256, 1.00*256, 1.00*256, 0)
```

How can I find better values for a tennis ball?

Comment: What colour is your tennis ball?

Comment: @RowlandShaw just the color of a normal tennis ball.

Comment: why not use actual object detection methods? how are you planning on detecting it?

Comment: Well, I've got pink ones, blue ones and yellow ones

Answer (score 0):

You should check only the H and S component, ignore the luma component. Furthermore, rather than hard coding the threshold values, you should use trackbars to set the values.